# How to programatically expand mat-rows in a Mat Table grid from the TS file?

Tags: angular

I have built a mat grid which allows multiple rows expansion at once , up-to three levels from the html .

There is some requirement where I need to expand the rows programmatically from the TS file . Any idea how can i achieve that ?

This is the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html) of the expandable mat-grid .

Please guide . TIA